# Adjust the placement of axis tick labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is my dataframe.

```
structure(list(start = c(1, 899, 1648, 2024, 4101, 6001, 7124, 
8982), end = c(898, 1647, 2023, 4100, 6000, 7123, 8981, 10000
), gene = c("A", "B", "C", "X", "P", "N", "O", "F"), annotation = c("Replicase", 
"transcription", "Metabolic Pathways", "Metabolic Pathways", 
"transcription", "transcription", "Antibiotic Resistance", "transcription"
), direction = c(1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1), p = c(449.5, 1273, 
1835.5, 3062, 5050.5, 6562, 8052.5, 9491)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this is the code I have written so far.

```
# Mean
filld$p <- rowMeans(subset(filld, select = c(start, end)))

# Plot
ggplot(filld, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = 4, ymax = 5, fill = annotation)) + # 
  geom_rect() +
  scale_x_continuous(label = label_bytes("kB"), breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
  geom_segment(data = subset(filld, gene %in% gene[duplicated(gene)]),
               aes(x = p, y = 0, xend = p, yend = 4, colour = annotation),
               size = 2) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = p, y = 4.5,
                     label = gene, 
                     family = 'Roboto Condensed',
                  ),  nudge_x = .15,
                  box.padding = 0.5,
                  nudge_y = 1,
                  segment.curvature = -0.1,
                  segment.ncp = 3,
                  segment.angle = 20,
                  size=3.5, min.segment.length = 0, max.overlaps = Inf) +
  coord_polar() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5.5)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), 
        #axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        #axis.ticks.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines"), 
        legend.position = "right", 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        #panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
        )
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

Now,

1. I want to adjust the placement of the axis tick labels (1Kb, 2Kb,..10Kb) so that they are inside the circle with ticks. This is to prevent any overlap with gene names that may be longer in length in the original dataset.
2. Additionally, I was wondering if it is possible to change the shape of the rectangle to an arrow, as depicted in the figure below.

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to put the axis text labels inside the circle would be to add the labels via a `geom_text` layer. Additionally, for the arrow shapes you could switch to `geom_segment`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(scales)

dat_x <- data.frame(
  x = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)(range(c(filld$start, filld$end)))
)

ggplot(filld) + #
  geom_segment(aes(x = start, xend = end - 100, y = 4.5, yend = 4.5, color = annotation),
    linewidth = 5, linejoin = "square",
    arrow = arrow(type = "closed", angle = 30),
    key_glyph = "rect"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    label = label_bytes("kB"), breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = subset(filld, gene %in% gene[duplicated(gene)]),
    aes(x = p, y = 0, xend = p, yend = 4, colour = annotation),
    size = 2
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = dat_x,
    aes(x = x, y = 3.75, label = label_bytes("kB")(x)),
    vjust = 1,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(
    aes(
      x = p, y = 4.5,
      label = gene,
      family = "Roboto Condensed",
    ),
    nudge_x = .15,
    box.padding = 0.5,
    nudge_y = 1,
    segment.curvature = -0.1,
    segment.ncp = 3,
    segment.angle = 20,
    size = 3.5, min.segment.length = 0, max.overlaps = Inf
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 5.5), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "right",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @stefan. This looks very nice too. Just exactly what I wanted to plot.

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably put a little bit of work into data-shaping and axis-faking. Using `geom_textpath`, we can get some fairly professional-looking results with direct labelling, and not a huge amount of code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(geomtextpath)

filld %>%
  group_by(gene, annotation) %>%
  summarise(x = c(start, end - c(200, 200, 20, 200, 200), start),
            y = c(17, 17, 16, 18, 20, 19, 19)/4) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = annotation, group = gene), 
               color = "black", linewidth = 0.3) +
  geom_textpath(aes(label = paste("gene", gene), x = p - 100, y = 5.2), 
                data = filld) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3.9, color = "gray60") +
  geom_line(aes(group = group), 
            data = data.frame(x = rep(0:9 * 1e3, each = 2),
                              y = rep(c(3.7, 3.9), 10),
                              group = rep(1:10, each = 2))) +
  geom_textpath(aes(label = paste(x, "kB")),
                data = data.frame(x = seq(0, 9000, 1000), y = 3.5)) +
  theme_void(base_size = 16) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#c00000", "#fdc000", "#308298", "#d8d8d8")) +
  ylim(0, 5.5) +
  xlim(0, 10000) +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is really, really nice, Allan.

Comment: Allan this looks amazing (no surprise). I cannot help but find that the font looks somehow "different". Am I wrong? Or do you indeed use a specific device or font or both?

Comment: @tjebo it's just the standard serif font R uses in Windows. The device is just `ragg`. In this case, it's copied directly from the RStudio plot viewer window.

Comment: The font looks rather "slim" to me, it's really nice. I am on a Mac, maybe it's really just that. I should start to use ragg by default as well. do you use ragg for your RStudio viewer too?

Comment: @tjebo I do, and I can't recommend it highly enough :)

Comment: This visualization looks absolutely fabulous! Thank you so much @Allan! But then in my original dataset I have many genes very close to each other, so I may need segments pointing to labels. But I will try to work on the code you provided.